# rendering algorithm suggestions

Tags: algorithm, raytracing

For a project in computer science I am to implement a further improvement to my ray-tracing renderer.

Features at the moment:

- SIMD implementation of ray-triangle intersection
- BVH using AABB. (SIMD ray-box intersection)
- Light calculations: Diffuse, Specular (reflection, refraction), Glossy Highlights
- HDR image based lighting
- Tone mapping

I'm looking for suggestions onto what algorithm that I might try to implement to win the rendering contest ;).

Requirements:

- Tough (challenging) and interesting, but yet doable for a 3 year bachelor student.
- Physically correct implementation.
- Good description research papers, implementation tutorials, or theory explained. (E.G. Slides)
- Should be able to be done in about 2 weeks time.
- Maybe something that would make me able to do physically based rendering of a character, hair, clothes and so on.